# current state of affairs in (systemic) functional grammar/linguistics?

Tags: reference-request, systemic-functional

What is the state of affairs in (systemic) functional grammar/linguistics in 2015 (rather than the state of affairs in the 1970s-1990s, when most of the books and papers I have were published)?

I'm asking because I'm thinking of delving deeper into functional grammar/linguistics (most probably systemic in particular), perhaps with an eye for (and prospects - albeit slim at best) for research some time in the future. I've got hold of quite a few books and tons of papers on SFL/SFG, but I'm finding it difficult to get even a semblance of a grip on the question above.

Answer (score 1):

It is still a very active branch of linguistics with conferences and journals and many linguists around the world participating.

See, e.g., the 42nd International Systemic Functional Congress at RWTH Aachen
( http://www.isfc2015.anglistik.rwth-aachen.de/ ) or the page of the International Systemic Functional Linguistics Association ( http://www.isfla.org/ ).

The conference programs should give you an impression on current topics in SFL.